# Java Annotation Refactoring

Tags: java, annotations

I have to functions with exactly the same contents but different annotation values.

import dagger.multibindings.StringKey;

```
@StringKey("valueA")
public void functionA() {
    // exactly same code here
}

@StringKey("valueB")
public void functionB() {
    // exactly same code here
}
```

How can I refactor functionA and functionB, so that I can add more values such as "valueC" without creating a new functionC?

Comment: Do `functionC` will do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper methods. You still make these methods, but they are oneliners:

```
@MyAnnotation("valueA")
public void functionA() {
  function0();
}

@MyAnnotation("valueB")
public void functionB() {
  function0();
}

private void function0() {
  // actual code here
}
```

Alternatively, you need to rewrite `MyAnnotation.java` as well as the code that interacts with it. I assume you can't do that (that it is an external library), in which case the above is the only answer.

Otherwise, you can make the `String value() default ""` line in `MyAnnotation.java` be `String[] value() default []` instead. Now you could write:

```
@MyAnnotation({"valueA", "valueB"})
public void functionBoth() {
  // this is the sole method
}
```

Or you can make a multi-annotation so that you can write:

```
@MyAnnotation("valueA")
@MyAnnotation("valueB")
public void functionBoth() {
  // this is the sole method
}
```